# Captive Portal for Android Phone

Tags: apache, captiveportal

As part of a homework assignment we were asked to build a Captive Portal in a Linux environment

In doing so, I found the very efficient article of [rootsh3ll](https://rootsh3ll.com/captive-portal-guide/), that I was indeed able to track and build the system as requested, but I got stuck in the user connection phase to the wireless point.

That is, after setting up the system, and after the user enters the wireless point we set up, and he enters his details, the system hangs and does not direct the user to continue browsing.

The logging page looks like this [image]

This is my android.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Servername connectivitycheck.gstatic.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/android

    RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 /index.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/android_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/android_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm focus only at android devices

Note that the apache main index.html page is containing a field which requesting a value from the user, thus when the user fills it and press Enter, the browser redirect him to: http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/loading.html?pass=

Also note that the index.html page contains the following `<form action=loading.html`
which is that I believe the redirect url contains this value

In the end, I would like to have the user to insert any value he wants, and by click Enter, he would be able to surf the internet properly, how can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone..?
I noticed that the line RedirectMatch 302 / generate_204 /index.html affects the whole process. But in fact it is an endless loop, because even if I redirect to go to generate_204 it goes back to the main page.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Can anyone share a single lonely hint? :S 
I'm really in the dark here